# How to Install Patch of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, patch

This might sound like a stupid question, But can anybody help me with how to install patch of Android Studio, Once i selected Download Updates from Android Studio, it directed to http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/ this page, From here i downloaded the .zip file, What next?
   How can I install that downloaded file, because it neither install automatically nor it had any setup.exe or something. 
So how can I update that patch?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using now?

Comment: @jomartigcal Now I am using 1.3

Comment: For me, a notification to update just came up on the top right when I opened Studio, I clicked Update, and it handled everything itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio links you to that page because with the latest version you have to make a clean install of the IDE due to some big changes in the software, so download the latest version from scratch and consider this in the future: Android Studio checks if there is any update available for your OS depending on which channel you're subscribed to, so there's no need to install any patch at all.

If you wish to install the very last update available you have to change the update channel to Canary Channel which is now on version 2.0

NB: The updates from the Canary channel are early stage updates, so they could have some bugs

To do this you have to:

1. Fire up Android Studio
2. Configure
3. Check for updates
4. In the pop up window, click on the blue "Updates" word
5. Check the first entry and select Canary Channel

Comment: In that case why they are linking to the .zip download, They should have link to the .exe file to download from scratch I guess?

So as per this should I completely do fresh setup of android studio?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend you to download the latest version and install it from scratch and import the previous settings because sometimes patches creates conflicts if not properly applied. By the way in that .zip there's the Android Studio software

Answer (score 4):

If any one finds an issue with actually using the update option(my connection kept spluttering out), this helped;
After downloading the patch file from the link given after the update fails;

Linux(Ubuntu);

```
java -classpath /tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio com.intellij.updater.Runner install android-studio/
```

Where **android-studio/** is the path to your AS installation.
**/tmp/jetbrains.patch.jar.androidstudio** is the path to the patch.

Windows;

```
java -classpath /path/to/AI-130.687321-130.692269-patch-unix.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install $PWD
```

[This](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56068) thread helped. Note that you must first close AS.

Comment: If you get a message about "jre/bin/java", make sure you have exited Android Studio and try again.

Comment: Just for information, $PWD is target directory, where your android studio is installed. Common place is "C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio". Also use " quotes around the path to allow spaces between two words like Program Files OR Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

I was struck for past 2 days like you by downloading the .zip file and wondering what to do next. That's very very simple.

1.**Unzip** the downloaded file.

2.Goto **android-studio -> bin** folder

In the ***bin*** folder you can find the **studio.exe** or **studio64.exe**, that is what you are looking for.

p.s : **studio.exe** is for **32-bit** and **studio64.exe** is for **64-bit** system.

I hope this is the answer you were looking for. If yes vote up and choose it as best answer. Because this is my first answer in stackoverflow :) .

Comment: My problem got solved like this only with @matt95 answer. Thank you